# Calculate bounding box of arbitrary pixel-based drawing

Tags: graphics, pixel, bounding-box, aabb

Given a contiguous drawing of arbitrary pixels (e.g. on an HTML5 Canvas) is there any algorithm for finding the axis-aligned bounding box that is more efficient than simply [looking at every pixel and recording the min/max x/y values](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_bounding_box.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine bounds of shape / graphics drawn into a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629396/determine-bounds-of-shape-graphics-drawn-into-a-canvas)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just scanline from top left to right and down to get y top,and similar algorithm with different directions for the rest.

---

*Edit by Phrogz:*

Here's a pseudo-code implementation. An included optimization ensures that each scan line does not look at pixels covered by an earlier pass:

```ruby
function boundingBox()
  w = getWidth()            # Assuming graphics address goes from [0,w)
  h = getHeight()           # Assuming graphics address goes from [0,h)
  for y=h-1 to 0 by -1      # Iterate from last row upwards
    for x=w-1 to 0 by -1    # Iterate across the entire row
      if pxAt(x,y) then
        maxY=y
        break               # Break out of both loops

  if maxY===undefined then  # No pixels, no bounding box
    return               

  for x=w-1 to 0 by -1      # Iterate from last column to first
    for y=0 to maxY         # Iterate down the column, up to maxY
      if pxAt(x,y) then
        maxX=x
        break               # Break out of both loops

  for x=0 to maxX           # Iterate from first column to maxX
    for y=0 to maxY         # Iterate down the column, up to maxY
      if pxAt(x,y) then
        minX=x
        break               # Break out of both loops

  for y=0 to maxY           # Iterate down the rows, up to maxY
    for x=0 to maxX         # Iterate across the row, up to maxX
      if pxAt(x,y) then
        minY=y
        break               # Break out of both loops

  return minX, minY, maxX, maxY
```

The result (in practice) performs about the same as the brute-force algorithm for a single pixel, and significantly better as the object gets larger.

#### Demo: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_bounding_box2.html

For fun, here's a visual representation of how this algorithm works:

[image]
        [image]
        [image]
        [image]
        [image]

It doesn't matter in what order you choose to do the sides, you just have to make sure that you take the previous results into account so that you are not double-scanning the corners.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use some kind of binary search, or sample on a coarse grid then a successively finer grid. The correctness of this method depends on if 'holes' are allowed in your drawing.

Comment: A binary search can easily fail if the graphic has any concave boundary portions.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike the current answer. Here's my code that I plugged into OP website. It's much faster in firefox and chrome.

The idea is check all pixels on x axis to see if there's a hit on the Y axis. If so update Y and increase X so we can scan for max X

```
function contextBoundingBox(ctx,alphaThreshold){
    if (alphaThreshold===undefined) alphaThreshold = 15;
    var w=ctx.canvas.width,h=ctx.canvas.height;
    var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data;

    let minX=w;
    let maxX=0
    let minY=h
    let maxY=0
    for(let y=0; y<h; y++)
    {
        for(let x=0; x<w; x++)
        {
            if (data[y*w*4 + x*4+3])
            {
                minX = Math.min(minX, x);
                maxX = Math.max(maxX, x);
                minY = Math.min(minY, y);
                maxY = y;
                x=maxX
            }
        }
    }

    return {x:minX,y:minY,maxX:maxX,maxY:maxY,w:maxX-minX,h:maxY-minY};
}
```