# AI is not giving actual text height

Tags: svg

I want to calculate actual height of the text, but the AI is giving the text height using the bounding box dimensions.

Please help me to calculate actual height of text!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with SVG. You might have to use a (hidden) `<canvas>` element, draw the text there and check what pixels were colored. Have e.g. a look at the simple [contextBoundingBox() function](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_bounding_box.html) by [Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852159/calculate-bounding-box-of-arbitrary-pixel-based-drawing).

Comment: How will i check colored pixels using the canvas code

Comment: Added link to a canvas based function. I didn't copy it here because it's not mine - it's @Phrogz